# How to send publish message request to Cloud pub/sub after two different logs has 'DONE' status in 'jobStatus'?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, stackdriver

I have setup a ETL tool which sends data from Oracle to Bigquery and continuously sends incremental data. When the data comes in, it creates a job and it is logged in Stackdriver Logging.

When the new incremental data comes in, some of those old data becomes unnecessary and I remove it using a query.

I setup a Log Sink with condition that when the new data comes in, send it as a message to Cloud pub/sub and use the Cloud pub/sub to trigger Cloud functions. Cloud functions makes an API call to Scheduled query which runs the query to remove the old data.

I have around 20 tables (Raw data table) with the same setup to remove old data from the respective table.

I have 5 tables (Business Intelligence table) which uses the 20 tables with some joins and where conditions.

This query is also running in a scheduled query in time based mode.

I want to run the scheduled query for Business Intelligence table manually when two or more raw data table's scheduled query has ran successfully.

I can see the log for each Scheduled query using the following advanced filter in Stackdriver logging:

```
resource.type="bigquery_resource" AND
protoPayload.requestMetadata.callerSuppliedUserAgent="BigQuery Data Transfer Service" AND
protoPayload.serviceData.jobInsertRequest.resource.jobConfiguration.query.destinationTable.tableId="aes_mapbin" AND
protoPayload.serviceData.jobInsertResponse.resource.jobStatus.state="DONE"
```

What I want to do was: Create a Log Sink for two/more Scheduled query for the above filter condition, If two Scheduled query has jobStatus as "DONE" then send a message to Cloud pub/sub which will trigger Cloud Functions that makes the API call to Scheduled Query which creates Business Intelligence Table.

Is it possible to do that? or Do I create a logic in Cloud functions python script to store the state in Cloud bucket or Bigquery itself then when there is a message again reset the values stored in?

My current python script for making an API call to Scheduled query:

```
import base64
from google.cloud import bigquery_datatransfer
from google.protobuf.timestamp_pb2 import Timestamp
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToJson

client = bigquery_datatransfer.DataTransferServiceClient()
project = 'projectID' 
parent = client.project_path(project)
start_time = Timestamp()   
start_time.GetCurrentTime()

def hello_pubsub(event, context):
    """Triggered from a message on a Cloud Pub/Sub topic.
    Args:
         event (dict): Event payload.
         context (google.cloud.functions.Context): Metadata for the event.
    """
    response = client.start_manual_transfer_runs(
        'Transfer configuration resource name',
        requested_run_time = start_time
        )
```

Comment: It is possible to filter the logs for completed Jobs with **proto_payload.method_name="jobservice.jobcompleted"**, [link](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/query-library#bigquery-filters). You can create a PubSub topic. Then you can export some of the filtered log messages to PubSub , so PubSub would be your "sink". Consequently,you can use it as a trigger to your Cloud Function, when creating it you can select PubSub as the trigger and select the topic.

Comment: Continuing my previous comment, In these two links you can read more about this procedure [link1](https://www.qwiklabs.com/focuses/8500?parent=catalog) and [link2](https://linuxacademy.com/hands-on-lab/97c3fd49-40bf-4cbd-adcf-e1107050fdef/). Is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes SAO did not show notification for your comment, I apologize for the very late response. I have achieved the sink and triggering the scheduled query from cloud function using cloud pub/sub. My intent was to trigger cloud function only when two cloud pub/sub topic have recieved message.